# Bluez, deinstallation before make from source?

Tags: linux, fedora, bluez

i am using Fedora 24. For my thesis, i have to build BlueZ from the source, because I need the experimental features.
Now, what is the best practice? Do I have to remove BlueZ from the OS before I can reinstall it from the source? When i try to remove bluez with dnf, he wanna also remove httpd and other applications as dependencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is probably to rebuild the RPM. We have bluez 5.39 in Fedora 23 (and 24) currently — this is one minor release behind the latest. If you need the newest, you could grab it from [Rawhide](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/source/tree/Packages/b/), Fedora's development branch.

Then, modify the spec file to enable the experimental features you need (presumably in this case by putting `--enable-experimental` on the `%configure` line.

When you modify the specfile, add something like `.experimental.1` to the end of the `Release:` field. That way, it will be counted as a newer update, and you can `dnf update bluez-5.39-1.fc23.experimental.1.x86_64.rpm`. (Update that final `.1` whenever you make a change, as a form of rudimentary version control.) Then, use [the DNF versionlock plugin](http://dnf-plugins-extras.readthedocs.io/en/latest/versionlock.html) to make sure updates don't override it, and when new versions come out, update at your leisure.

Comment: Thank you, and i have to do this on every update of BlueZ manually right? Do i have to remove the installation of BlueZ 5.40 before?

Comment: @datafridge Edited to add some best practices addressing that.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have a last little question. I've tried to remove bluez and, as I wrote dnf also want to deinstall gnome-tweak-tool, gdm and other stuff. I get the hint from the IRC Channel #fedora, that I could disable clean_requirements_on_remove in the /etc/dnf/dnf.conf file. I set it to "False", but nothing changes? Did I have to do something else?